# Fixing this MySQL query to output correct number of games played & win percentage?

Tags: mysql

I am using the following query to look into a results table and display the win% of various players' matches against each other.

```
SELECT 
T.member
, count(*) Wins 
, total.gamesPlayed
, count(*)/total.gamesPlayed as winPercentage
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        player2_name as member 
    from results 
    WHERE 
        player1_id = 2 
        AND player1_result = 'W' 
        AND community_id = 16 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 
        player1_name 
    FROM results 
        WHERE player2_id = 2
        AND player2_result = 'W' 
        AND community_id = 16
) AS T 
,   (
        select
            u.member
            , sum(u.gamesPlayed) as gamesPlayed
        from
            (
                select
                    player2_name as member
                    , count(*) gamesPlayed
                from results
                where
                    player1_id = 2 
                    AND community_id = 16 
                group  by player2_name
                union
                select
                    player1_name as member
                    , count(*) gamesPlayed
                from results
                where
                    player2_id = 2 
                    AND community_id = 16 
                group  by player2_name
            ) as u /* union of two */
        group by member 
) as total
where
T.member = total.member
group by T.member 
ORDER BY Wins DESC
```

The correct output should be:

`+---------+-----------+---------------+---------+
| member  |    Wins   | Games Played  |  Win %  |
+---------+-----------+---------------+---------+
| Player 1|     3     |       4       |    0.75 |
| Player 2|     2     |       2       |    1.00 |
+---------+-----------+---------------+---------+`

But I am currently getting:

`+---------+-----------+---------------+---------+
| member  |    Wins   | Games Played  |  Win %  |
+---------+-----------+---------------+---------+
| Player 1|     3     |       1       |    3.00 |
| Player 2|     2     |       5       |    0.40 |
+---------+-----------+---------------+---------+`

As you can see, the fault appears to be in the Games Played column fetching incorrect data.  How do I correct my query to get the result I am after?

Comment: i think you should recheck the second union part of your query.. the second query is using the GROUP BY wrong.. you select player1_name and the group is on player2_name.. i think you need to group by on player1_name

Comment: Nearly there! I think you were correct, though for some strange reason it is correctly showing 4 games played against player 1, but only 1 (instead of 2) for player 2....

Comment: fixed it, I added `all` to the last 'union' and it reported correctly